# Dapper and Oracle parametrized query - ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

I'm currently trying my hand on Dapper. The following code works flawlessly:

```
using (var conn = 
    new OracleConnection(
        "Uid=dbusr;Pwd=dbusrpwd;Server=oraserver;"))
{
    var col = 
        conn.Query<User>(
        "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = 'uid01'"
        , null)
        .ToList();
}
```

But if instead of using a hardcoded parameter I try to pass it through a parametrized query plus an anonymous class, like this:

```
using (var conn = 
    new OracleConnection(
        "Uid=dbusr;Pwd=dbusrpwd;Server=oraserver;"))
{
    var col = 
        conn.Query<User>(
        "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @Id"
        , new { Id = "uid01" })
        .ToList();
}
```

I receive the following error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

I searched around SO, but found no similar error reports; it seems I'm missing something terribly obvious but alas - I ran out of coffee. I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In oracle's flavour of SQL, named parameters are prefixed with `:`. Try `:Id` instead of `@Id`.

Comment: And that's exactly the terribly obvious thing I was talking about. Thanks so much, Marc - worked like a charm!

Comment: @Ono I'm just glad you could get a fairly quick answer; I've been there... (sometimes it feels like I spend days there)

Comment: Abusively fast, you mean. Can't get any luckier than that; once again, thanks!